# jquery/ javascript slider realtime based

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to implement a slider on top of every page of my website. 
however this might be disturbing and annoying when a user starts browsing from page to page, since the slideshow will start over and over again.

I though the solution could lay in the builtin date function:

```
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getSeconds(); 
    if(n%10 == 0)
    {
    rotate
    }
```

Or perhaps I could set a cookie with the values from the slider when a user leaves that page (name=topSlider value=1 time=300), so the new page could pick it up and go further in  it's sequence.

Comment: And the issue is? ps. you can use localStorage/SessionStorage.

Comment: That the automatic slider/ carousel on every page refresh restarts at slide 1, while I wish it could just keep going.  exemple: If I am at home page and the slide is currently on the third element I wish that the slider can just start at slide 3 instead of one after  a new page is loaded

Comment: Then load your content inside the page dynamically. Look up $.load(). Plenty on it on SO.

Comment: so with other word, I shall call the content of all pages thru one page?

Comment: Yes. If you don't want to reload parts of the page (such as your slider) of course.

Comment: is it some sort of iframe?

Comment: No. Did you look it up? You can load external html to DOM elements.

Comment: Thats not rlly what I want, I want to maintain the current browsing behavior in folders and different links etc